# Multiple Conditional mapping in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I need a little help with some mappings I am doing.

I am mapping a Model which has two fields

```
public ProductCategory
public string FirstType
public string SecondType
```

to another Model which has only one field

```
public string ProductType
```

Now I have to map the First or Second Type to ProductType based on a the content of ProductCategory.And if the condition is not met the ProductType should be null

For example I need something like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ProductType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
{
   if (src.ProductCategory.Equals("something")
     { 
        src.FirstType
     }
   else if (src.ProductCategory.Equals("something")
     {
        src.SecondType
     }
   else 
    {
       null 
    }
}))
```

Of course the syntax is completely wrong and obviously won`t work , I just wanted to explain what I am trying to achieve.

I have a temporary solution

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ProductType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProductCategory.Contains("something") ? src.FirstType: src.SecondType))
```

but it is not completely what I need.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you actually extract this onto a method? It might clean up a bit

Comment: You mean instead using AutoMapper?

Comment: Nono, you can use AutoMapper but extracting the variable result from a method. Something like `.ForMember(dest => dest.ProductType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => CalculateProductCategory(src.ProductCategory)))` and then you write your own `CalculateProductCategory` method

Comment: Right, it can work this way , thanks a lot. The only problem is that I have 5 or 6 fields like that which have to be populated based on the same condition , so I have to write 5-6 methods for every field, but it is still a solution to my problem

Comment: You can reuse [resolvers](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html) and, for the latest, [value converters](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-converters.html).

Comment: thanks, i looked into it but I am working with existing code and I am trying to make as few changes as possible

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to avoid making the map code look very tangled is to actually separate it into methods that you actually know require some checking for the right value to be assigned.

Here's the code

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.ProductType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => CalculateProductCategory(src.ProductCategory))) and then you write your own CalculateProductCategory
```

And your method would look something like this

```
    public ProductType CalculateProductCategory(ProductCategory category) {

    if (productCategory.Equals("something")
    { 
        return FirstType
    }
    else if (productCategory.Equals("something")
    {
        return SecondType
    }
    else 
    {
       return null 
    }

}
```